# Unable to run python script - Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, python

Trying to run a NZBGet (Python) Script, I've tried to run manually with:

```
/mnt/local/ext001/MEDIA/NZBGet/scripts/videosort/VideoSort.py
```

but this results in:

```
bash: /mnt/local/ext001/MEDIA/NZBGet/scripts/videosort/VideoSort.py: Permission denied
```

I've tried running this as `sudo` and `SU` and permissions are `777` currently, but still get the same message.  How can permission be denied?

EDIT:
It seems the partition is mounting with noexec, despite using the following:

```
/mnt/local/ext001 ext4 auto,rw,exec,async,user,suid,noatime,nodiratime,relatime 0 2
```

Any idea why it is not accepting the exec option?

Comment: When you're situated in `../videosort/ dir`, could you run the script without problems?

Comment: Every time you do chmod 777, somewhere in the world a kitten dies

Comment: Is the partition mounted with `noexec`?

Comment: @janos I changed it to 777 to test it, surely if it is 777 it should be fine to execute with open permissions?

Comment: @MarkWagner no, it is exec: /mnt/local/ext001 ext4 auto,rw,exec,async,user,suid,noatime,nodiratime,relatime 0 2

Comment: @tachomi running VideoSort or VideoSort.py results in `bash: VideoSort.py: command not found`.

Comment: Ok, after checking a similar post, I tried `mount` and the partition IS mounted as noexec, why is this despite using `exec`.  Does the mount options need to be in a specific order?

Comment: Can you please check the first line in the file. It should start with `#!` and should be followed by the path to your python interpreter e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the order of the mount options is important here. From the man page:

> ```
>    users  Allow every user to mount  and  unmount  the  filesystem.   This
>           option  implies  the  options  noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless
>           overridden  by  subsequent  options,  as  in  the  option   line
>           users,exec,dev,suid).
> ```

The `exec` option is before the `users` option, not subsequent to it, so the `users` option overrides it and sets the volume to `noexec`.

Answer (score 1):

If python is executable and you don't want to remount partition (or can't), you can just run:

```
python /mnt/local/ext001/MEDIA/NZBGet/scripts/videosort/VideoSort.py
```

If you want to run a elf(linux binary executable file) file without the execute permission, you can:

> /lib/ld-linux.so.*  /path/to/elf/file

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked, but it did not fix the problem, not being able to execute the python script was just the symptom in this case.  But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need make your file executable.

```
chmod +x /mnt/local/ext001/MEDIA/NZBGet/scripts/videosort/VideoSort.py
```

or

```
chmod 555 /mnt/local/ext001/MEDIA/NZBGet/scripts/videosort/VideoSort.py
```

then, you can run that:

```
./mnt/local/ext001/MEDIA/NZBGet/scripts/videosort/VideoSort.py.
```

Comment: It was already executable, I was using incorrect placement of /etc/fstab mount options, this resulted in it being mounted as 'noexec'.  Thanks for your input however.

Comment: what's the key difference between `chmod +x` and `chmod 555`?

Answer (score 0):

In some compilers, like `vsCode`, you need to type "python" instead of "python3" to overcome that.

Eg -:

```
python manage.py startapp chat
```